# Update a template with Mustache js

Tags: javascript, mustache

I`m using mustache js to render a template with data from API and works nice, but i need to update (re-render) same template after a while. In my case I have a list in template like this:

**template.html**

```
<div id="template">
  {{#list}}
    <span>{{firstName}} {{lastName}} - {{phone}}</span>
  {{/list}}
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax(
    //some ajax here
  ).done(function(response){
    loadTemplate(response);
  });

});

function loadTemplate(data){
  var template = $("#template").html();
  Mustache.parse(template);
  var render = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
  $("#template").empty().html(render);
};
```

But the user can add more elements on this list, and after that I need to update the mustache template. I tried call the Ajax (that response with new value add on the list) then call loadTemplate function again but does not work, the list does not change (update) with new values.

Comment: Not working is too general.. seems like you override the template every time. Please specify - what is the structure of your response and does it represents a single item (which need to be added to the template) or a list of items (which should override the entire template)

Comment: @ymz, thanks... I edit the questio, could u help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time you render the template, the original mustache template gets lost. 
**ONLY** the rendered text exists in same location. So the second time you try to re-render the template there is no template to render simply text that is NOT a template anymore so the text is simply outputed again.

The solution is to store your original template in another location (eg inside an element with `id=#originalTemplate`).

Then do following:

```
function loadTemplate(data){
  var template = $("#originalTemplate").html(); // NOTE we use original template which does not get overriden
  Mustache.parse(template);
  var render = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
  $("#template").empty().html(render);
};
```

Comment: Nice, I change your solution and salve the original template in the window object. Thanks!